# PDU Response Parameters

Tags: smpp, pdu

I'm creating a SMPP server using Node.js.

It's all okay, but now, I have to send to client a custom parameter inside pdu.response(), like 'message_id'.

If I do:

```
session.send(pdu.response({comand_status: 999}));
```

It works, but if I do

```
session.send(pdu.response({message_id: 999}));
```

I always receive

```
PDU {
    command_length: 16,
    command_id: 2432432,
    command_status: 0,
    sequence_number: 1,
    command: 'bind_transceiver_resp' }
```

So, I have a question. Can I do this? Or it's impossible using SMPP?

Answer (score 0):

No,you cannot actually add any custom parameters to the pdu response.but,try to check the optional parameters whether it is fitting your needs